# Google API Testing on non 'localhost' named local server

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm currently running MAMP Pro (osX 10.9.4) with several different virtual servers on my local machine, one for each of my client's projects. I've been trying to connect to the Google API use OAuth and have everything working just fine when 'REDIRECT URIS' is set to:

```
http://localhost:8888
```

However, as mentioned I've got several of these servers running,

```
e.g. 'https://clientname1:8890' or 'https://clientname2:8890'
```

Whenever I enter those into the API console I just get a 'Whoops' message telling me something has gone wrong Google's end:

"Server Error: Whoops! Our bad."

It seems as though only 'localhost' is allowed via the API for local testing, is there anyway I can set it up so I can test off any of my local servers?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add my localhost to the allowed referrers list to test locally. Without that inclusion, I get 403 Forbidden errors. You probably just need to add clientname1 and clientname2 or clientname1:8890 and clientname2:8890 to the allowed referrers list in the Google Developers Console. Mine's set under public api access, so maybe it's going to be another problem for you depending what API you're using and how you're using it. Hope it helps -

[image]